# Why is my simple function not working?

Tags: javascript, html

Below is my HTML code. I've tried everything I can but I can't get this function to work. Thanks in advance.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>How many fingers?</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>Guess how many fingers I am holding up </p>

<!-- <input type="text" id="fingers"> -->

<p><input type="text" id="guess"><button id="checkGuess">Guess</button></p>
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("checkGuess").onlick = function () {
    alert("hi!");
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Correction: Working*

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you have a misspelling:

This: `document.getElementById("checkGuess").onlick`

Should be: `document.getElementById("checkGuess").onclick`

The missing "c" might solve your issue.